# Dynamic connection to Database ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-core, database-connection, connection-string

I want write autorization system in asp.net - user of Postgres (which created throws CREATE ROLE...) entering login and password and working with own tables. Problem is i working in ASP.NET core and connecting throws Dapper.

appsettings.json

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
  },
  "DBInfo": {
    "Name": "coresample",
    "ConnectionString": "User ID=username;Password=userpassword;Host=localhost;Port=5432;Database=Documents;Pooling=true;"
  }
}
```

DocumentsRepository

```
public class DocumentsRepository : IRepository<Documents>
    {
        private string connectionString;

        public DocumentsRepository(IConfiguration configuration, string login, string password)
        {
            connectionString = configuration.GetValue<string>("DBInfo:ConnectionString");
            connectionString = connectionString.Replace("username", login);
            connectionString = connectionString.Replace("userpassword", password);
        }

        internal IDbConnection Connection
        {
            get
            {
                return new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString);
            }
        }

        public void Add(Documents item)
        {
            using (IDbConnection dbConnection = Connection)
            {
                dbConnection.Open();
                dbConnection.Execute("SELECT addrecuserdocuments(@DocumentName,@Contents,@DocumentIntroNumber)", item);
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable<Documents> FindAll()
        {
            using (IDbConnection dbConnection = Connection)
            {
                dbConnection.Open();
                return dbConnection.Query<Documents>("SELECT * FROM selectdata()");
            }
        }
```

DocumentController

```
public class DocumentsController : Controller
    {
        private readonly DocumentsRepository dRepository;

        public DocumentsController(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            dRepository = new DocumentsRepository(configuration);
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(dRepository.FindAll());
        }

        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Documents/Create
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Create(DocumentViewModel dvm)
        {
            Documents docs = new Documents { DocumentName = dvm.DocumentName, DocumentIntroNumber = dvm.DocumentIntroNumber };

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (dvm.Contents != null)
                {
                    byte[] imageData = null;
                    using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(dvm.Contents.OpenReadStream()))
                    {
                        imageData = binaryReader.ReadBytes((int)dvm.Contents.Length);
                    }
                    docs.Contents = imageData;
                }
                dRepository.Add(docs);
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(docs);
        }
```

In Startup.cs i connection throws 
services.AddSingleton(Configuration);

Please, help me understand, how i can call connection string and transfering login and password of user? And where? And is it possible?

Please, i realy need help with this!